# How can I convert cross apply in SQL Server to Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to migrate the below update statement from SQL Server to Teradata:

Below is the code in MS SQL SERVER that I want to migrate:

```
Update x
set x.a = isnull(cast(x.b as date),Date)
from table x
cross apply schema.middateperd(period)
```

`middateperd` is a table value function and below is the function definition:

return
{ select convert(date, period, 110) as Date}

I am expecting to migrate this to Teradata without using any function

Comment: Question does not make sense.  (1) Do you have the function defined in Teradata?  (2) Why are you using a table-valued function if the function is returning only one row.  (3) If the function returns multiple rows, why is it being used in an `update`?

Comment: What exactly doe `middateperd()` return?

Comment: `select convert(date, period, 110)`is not valid T-SQL, what's `period`? Btw, you're not using `middateperd` in SET or WHERE.

Comment: Updating my question

Comment: middateperiod is used in update.It's cross applied

Comment: Why are you using a table-valued function if the function is returning only one row/column? And why do you want to achieve this in *Teradata without using any function*, you got a TVF in SQL Server? `to_date(period, 'mm-dd-yyyy')` should return the same.

Comment: Hi All, I have implemented the function defintion in the set statement itself. The reason why I asked this question is I was not sure, how the function was joining with the base table in the query.. The column period is transformed into a date column and this cant be joined with period from the base table...Anyways, it's working for now.